# Size of a array access by pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, size

I search to calculate the size of my array.
To do that, as usual, I divide the size of my array by the size of a cell.
When I try with the array it's work, but if I use the pointer on my array, I find a really strange value.

Please, could you enlighten me ?

Here, my code:

```
int tab1K_I[1000];
int * tab1k_p = tab1K_I;

int c,v;
c = sizeof (tab1k_p) / sizeof(*tab1k_p);
printf("c : %d\r\n", c);

v = sizeof (tab1K_I) / sizeof(tab1K_I[0]);
printf("v :%d\r\n", v);

c = 2;
v = 1000;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array))
```

works only on **arrays**. In your code, `int * tab1k_p` is **not** an **array**, it's a **pointer**, thus your method doesn't work.

`sizeof(tab1K_I)` is `sizeof(int[1000])` which is `sizeof(int) * 1000`, thus `ARRAY_LENGTH(tab1K_I)` equals `sizeof(int)`.

However, `sizeof(tab1k_p)` is `sizeof(int *)`, which is not the same as `sizeof(int[1000])`, and thus `ARRAY_LENGTH(tab1k_p)` yields `sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int)`, which does not produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and pointers are both allocated on stack. But when array is allocated its size is predefined at compile time. Pointers on the other hand only allocate space to store an address.

Here, tab1k_p pointer takes 8 bytes on stack (sizeof(*int) is 8 on 64 bit systems). tab1K_I takes 1000*4 (ie: 1000 * sizeof(int)) from your stack.

*tab1k_p is the first element of the array because of the assignment. First element of the array is int. sizeof(int) is 4. Thus,

`sizeof (tab1k_p) / sizeof(*tab1k_p);` is 8/4 = 2.

`sizeof (tab1K_I) / sizeof(tab1K_I[0])` is 4000/4 = 1000.